Open CV Image color filter to extract precise area under each color
I have some GPR (ground-penetrating RADAR) data set in .jpg format[Imge attached]. Need to read them and feed them to an Excel sheet. I need each color's rectangle length by pixel value to process the data further. The color detection and precise length of their rectangles are required as an output. Original image to be processed
My plan is to detect the color by passing it through several color filters and then creating a bounding box around them to get their length. I have tried to re-adjust the HSV value several times but colors are not getting detected properly. Here is a code to filter only the red color rectangles from these images.

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('Image15.jpg')

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define the range of red color in HSV
lower_red = np.array([0, 50, 50])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only red colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
filtered_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

# Display the original and filtered images
cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
cv2.imshow('Filtered Image', filtered_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Original Image
Filterd Image
It has missed some of the blocks on the left side and some at the center. But I really can't understand the unpredictability of this filter. Please guide me on how I can precisely detect the colored rectangles' lengths.

In HSV, H for red needs two ranges -- one on each side of 0. That is low values near 0 and high values near 180 in OpenCV.  I think you have only the first near 0 and missed the ones near 180.

that's an illustration. I'd recommend getting the actual sensor data and annotations from whatever program controlled the radar device.
